# Jira PHP SOAP updateissue doesnt work

Tags: php, jira

I tried updating component for issue in Jira using SOAP in PHP, it didnt throw any exception, it returned isuue but component was never updated.

Any ideas?

here is my sample code:

```
$myIssue="";

$myIssue['components'][] = array("id" => "10769", "name" => "component name");

$soap->updateIssue($auth,"ISSUEKEY", $myIssue);
```

It just returns issue without any change to component.

This is what is sent out of php when i print that variable :

```
Array
(
    [components] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10769
                    [name] => component name
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a PHP developer, but I think that this code:

```
arrayToObject(array("id" => "10769", "name" => "component name")
```

Results in this:

```
{
    id: '10769',
    name: 'component name'
}
```

Am I right?

Which would result in this being sent to JIRA as the RemoteFieldValue Array:

```
{components: [{
    id: '10769',
    name: 'component name'
}]}
```

If so, I do not think that is what jira is expecting. I believe it is expecting:

```
[
    {id: 'components',value:'component name'}
]
```

Remember that Java does not have associative arrays. So the construct $myIssue['components'][] doesn't mean anything to Java. Java also does not support multi-dimensional arrays of different types.

### Update:

Try this (Or something like it, my code is not tested):

```
<?php

    class RemoteFieldValue {
        var $id;
        var $values = array();

        function __construct($idIn, $valuesIn) {
            $this->id = $idIn;
            $this->values = $valuesIn;
        }
    }

    $rfv = new RemoteFieldValue('components', array("id" =>"componentid_goes_here"));

    $rfvArray = array($rfv);

    $soap->updateIssue($auth,"ISSUEKEY", $rfvArray);


?>
```

When I put together a JIRA service in ColdFusion I implemented each JIRA object (User, Issue, RemoteFieldValue, etc) as a ColdFusion object. I suspect you could also do it with associative arrays and arrays, but I find this cleaner and it makes it easier to adapt to what the JIRA SOAP service expects.

Comment: you are right. I was passing as array before, but when i saw it was not working and in returned issue it was showing components contained std_object i tried to change code to send object to see it works but no luck with that too :(....

Comment: Can you update your question to show the new code so we can see if we can figure out why it's still not working?

Comment: Sorry, I got confused because you are still using a multi-dimensional array. Which Java will not understand. It is only expecting an array of objects. Can you serialize the output of that object you are sending?

Comment: added the output of variable that is being sent to jira.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a suggestion. Please recall that I am not a PHP developer, so my code/syntax might be hosed.

Comment: i get following error now :

 com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteValidationException: Fields not valid for issue: 
Errors: {components=Component/s is required.}

Comment: i got it with littlebit modification :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to update a field is to pass the object

First define the class (generated from the WSDL)

```
class RemoteFieldValue {
  public $id; // string
  public $values; // ArrayOf_xsd_string
}
```

Create object

```
$remoteField = new RemoteFieldValue ();
$remoteField->id = "12345"; 
$remoteField->value = "bla";
```

then call the method

```
$soap->updateIssue($auth,"ISSUEKEY", $remoteField );
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

For me updateIssue works in such way (php)

Defining class (from wsdl)

```
class RemoteFieldValue 
{
  public $id; // string
  public $values; // ArrayOf_xsd_string
}
```

after that here is a code which updates 'description' field at issue.

```
public function updateDescription($issue_key, $description)
{
$remoteField = new RemoteFieldValue ();
$remoteField->id = 'description'; 
$remoteField->values = array($description); 

return $this->mSoapClient->updateIssue($this->mToken, $issue_key, array($remoteField));            
}
```